# How to split inline JS expressions by lines in vue templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js, coding-style

I clashed with the problem when had written this code:

```
<span
  class="deal-card__cost"
>{{ deal.total_cost | currency(
                        '₽',
                        0,
                        {
                          thousandsSeparator: ' ',
                          symbolOnLeft: false,
                          spaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol: true
                        }
                      ) | placeholder('- - -') }}</span>
```

And it can't be parsed.
Is it possible in Vue templates to split inine JS expressions? If yes - how?

Comment: Use a method instead of doing all that in the template.

Answer (score 4):

[From the guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

> In-template expressions are very convenient, but they are meant for
> simple operations. Putting too much logic in your templates can make
> them bloated and hard to maintain.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <div id="example"> 
>   {{ message.split('').reverse().join('') }}
> </div>
> ```
>
> At this point, the template is no longer simple and declarative. You
> have to look at it for a second before realizing that it displays
> message in reverse. The problem is made worse when you want to include
> the reversed message in your template more than once.
>
> That’s why for any complex logic, you should use a **computed property**.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a computed property [Computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage: function () {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <p>Original message: "{{ message }}"</p>
  <p>Computed reversed message: "{{ reversedMessage }}"</p>
</div>
```